# WPF write Add log generic function

Tags: wpf, log4net

So i am using `Log4Net` in my application.

And beside the `.txt` file i have another `List` that populate once my `Logger` form is opening.

So currently i am add `.txt` `Log` this way:

```
log.Info("My message");
```

And i have another function that add `log` into my `List`:

```
public static ObservableCollection<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
public static void AddLog(Level level, string message, string source)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry()
        {
            DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff"),
            Index = LogEntries.Count + 1,
            Level = level,
            Source = source,
            Message = message
        };

        LogEntries.Add(logEntry);
    }));
}
```

Usage:

```
LogHelper.AddLog(Level.Info, "My message", $"{ GetType().Name }\\{ MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name }");
```

So now every time i want to add log i wrote it this way:

```
log.Info("My message");
LogHelper.AddLog(Level.Info, "My message", $"{ GetType().Name }\\{ MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name }");
```

So i want to try a way to send to my generic function all the relevant data (`Level level, string message, string source`) in inside this function add also the log into my `.txt` file but my problem is that i cannot know how to do that because after the `log` i need to specify the `Level` for example:

```
log.Error...
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: `if (level == Level.Info) log.Info(...); else if (level == Level.Error) log.Error(...);` etc

Comment: Yes but because i define my log to show also the class and method name ( [%logger/%method]) this means that all my logs will show that come from same class and same method